# How user string input will show as background color in a div in react JS functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I am trying to make a color box where users can input color as a string but will display output as a background color in react
I tried this way but it did not work as expected I am just learning to react. thanks in advance
Here is my code.**

```
import "./styles.css";
import randomColor from "randomcolor";
import { useState } from "react";
let color = randomColor();
// const name = "rocky";
export default function App() {
  const [statecolor, setcolor] = useState({
    bg:"",
    dis:false
  });

  function displayColor(e) {
    const inputcolor = e.target.value;
    if (inputcolor === color) {
      setcolor( prevValues => {
        return { ...prevValues,bg:color,dis:true}
      
     } )
    }else{
      console.log("not found")
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>show color with input matching</h1>
      {statecolor.map((statecolors)=>{
        return (
          <h2 style={{backgroundColor:statecolors}}>{statecolors}</h2>
        )
      })}
      
     
      <input type="text" value={statecolor} onChange={displayColor} />
    </div>
```

);
}

Comment: I think you should save an array instead of object, and what is `dis` for?

Comment: dis for initial background color set false, I did with an array but it displays color but I wanted to display when user input is "red" output automatically display red in the box

Comment: I dont get it, you're not using that in your code anyway

Comment: @Andara here is my code sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-banach-0zwqg where I tried with the array it shows random color without any input. I want to change color with user input. would you like to help where did I mess up...

Comment: sure, but what do you want to achieve by checking this `inputcolor === color`?

Comment: @Andara I wanted to match random color with user input: for example if user type "red" should display as a red background color as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want to achieve, but here's what I wrote
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-thunder-jlc28?file=/src/App.js

- randomColor is unused actually because you doesn't want to display initially right?
- I'm not sure why checking this `inputcolor === color`, it will always go to `else` (unless you know what the randomColor will be) so I skipped that part

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing the background color because you're not setting it to a proper value. `statecolors` is an object, but you're setting the entire object as the value in your code. You need to access `statecolors.bg` and set that. Assuming the user enters it as a proper value, hex or color, then the below would work:

```
      {statecolor.map((colorObject)=>{
        return (
          <h2 style={{backgroundColor:colorObject.bg}}>{statecolors}</h2>
        )
      })}
```

Comment: I did exactly what was put here but display "statecolor.map " is not function

Comment: Your code had statecolor.map so I figured your actual code had this as an array and you typoed lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayColor(e) {
    const inputcolor = e.target.value;
    if (inputcolor) {
      setcolor( prevValues => {
        return { ...prevValues,bg:inputcolor,dis:true}
      
     } )
    }else{
      console.log("not found")
    }
  }
```

======================

```
{statecolor.map((colorObject)=>{
        return (
          <h2 style={{backgroundColor:colorObject.bg}}>{statecolors}</h2>
        )
      })}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).